# How to create a query in Axapta?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

This is related to a my previous question. I've a (not so) 'complex' query with 3 joined table. This is the query:

```
    select  somefield
from WMSTRANSPORT INNER join GMSWmslocationwrkctr On WMSTRANSPORT.TOLOCATION = GMSWMSLOCATIONWRKCTR.WMSLOCATIONID
inner join WMSLOCATIONSUM on WMSTRANSPORT.TOLOCATION = WMSLOCATIONSUM.WMSLOCATIONID
where 
EXPEDITIONSTATUS=3 OR EXPEDITIONSTATUS =4
```

How to 'convert' into X++ code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the ON clauses to WHERE clauses, use == instead of =, and use || instead of OR:

```
select somefield
from WMSTRANSPORT 
where (WMSTRANSPORT.EXPEDITIONSTATUS==3 || WMSTRANSPORT.EXPEDITIONSTATUS==4)
join GMSWmslocationwrkctr where WMSTRANSPORT.TOLOCATION == GMSWMSLOCATIONWRKCTR.WMSLOCATIONID
join WMSLOCATIONSUM where WMSTRANSPORT.TOLOCATION == WMSLOCATIONSUM.WMSLOCATIONID
```

Comment: Thank you. Another question: how to bind this query to a grid ? Is it possible ?

Comment: No you'll have to build a Query object and pass it to the form's datasource.

Comment: This article describes how to work with multiple joined data sources on an AOT Query object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa880078(v=ax.50).aspx